# how to populate multiple divs with dynamic data from an array or json in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets assume I have an array/json with 5 objects. A person object with 3 fields. name, age, sex.

```
<div>
    <div class="person">
      <label for="name">Name: </label> <span id="name"></span><br>
      <label for="age">Age: </label> <span id="age"></span><br>
      <label for="sex">Sex: </label> <span id="sex"></span><br>
      <button type="button" class="bdel" id="button">Delete person</button>   
    </div>   
</div>
```

How do I populate and generate 5 divs? 1 div for 1 object.
It should look something like the following:

```
<div>
    <div class="person>
    <div class="person>
    <div class="person>
    <div class="person>
    <div class="person>
</div>
```

I would rather not have too much of html in my jquery file, because in the real project I assume that I might have more than just 3 fields/elements.

Comment: if you can post the response data it's quite easy

Comment: something like `yourJsonArray.forEach(function(person, index) {$('<div>'+ person.name +'</div>').appendTo(yourContainer);});`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jQuery templates](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl)

```js
var items = [{
  id: 0,
  name: 'Test'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Test 2'
}];
$("#myTemplate").tmpl(items).appendTo(".container");
```

```css
.person {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>

<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <div class="person">
    <label for=" name${id} ">Name:</label> <span id="name${id} ">${name}</span>
  </div>
</script>
<div class='container'>
</div>
```

Or, You can iterate and create DOM fragment and append it.

```js
var items = [{
  id: 0,
  name: 'Test'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Test 2'
}];

items.forEach(function(item) {
  var div = $('<div>', {
    "class": "person"
  });
  var span = $('<span>', {
    "text": item.name,
    "id" : "name" + item.id
  })
  div.append(span).appendTo(".container");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = []; // your array of objects
```

If you want to insert the divs in the let's say element having id 'container'.

```
var containerElm = document.getElementById('container');
var str = '';
for(var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++){
   var divStr = '<div class="person">'+
             '<label for="name">Name: </label> <span id="name">'+data[i].name+'</span><br>'+
             '<label for="age">Age: </label> <span id="age">'+data[i].age+'</span><br>'+
             ' <label for="sex">Sex: </label> <span id="sex">'+data[i].sex+'</span><br>'+
             '<button type="button" class="bdel" id="button">Delete person</button> '+
             '</div> ';
   str = str + divStr;
 }
containerElm.innerHTML = str;
```